# In Python, how do I parse each word in a text file and make each word lowercase and remove special characters except for apostrophes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, special-characters, lowercase

This is the code I have so far. It lower-cases each word in the input file but I am unsure how to check and remove special characters, except for apostrophes, from the input file.

```
input("Please enter a file name: ")
    with open(input(), 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            for word in line.split():
                word.lower()
```

Comment: What's a word? What's a special character? Please define this specifically otherwise we can't help you. English words? Series of ascii characters delimited by spaces? Word in any language? Do you have a particular dictionary?

Comment: You should store the return value in a variable and then you can continue by defining what a special character actually is.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are just trying to read the input file and not overwrite it, so what I wrote up just prints the result out.

You can use the Python String isalnum() Method
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isalnum.asp

according to the doc:
"The isalnum() method returns True if all the characters are alphanumeric, meaning alphabet letter (a-z) and numbers (0-9)."

Assuming that meets your requirements, the following should work.

```
    alphanumeric = ""
    with open(r"C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\test.txt", 'r') as input_file:
      for line in input_file:
        for c in line:
           if c == "'":
              alphanumeric += "'"
           elif c == " ":
              alphanumeric += " "
           elif c.isalnum():
              alphanumeric += c
     print(alphanumeric.lower())
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
re.sub(ur'[^a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

Comment: Care to expand to explain *how* and *why* this is expected to function?  Looks like a random (non-functional) answer to me.  Additionally, this will not convert each word to lower case, and will not work if the file is read into a list ... should I go on?  Yes. And `re.sub` expects three arguments.  This does not tell what string is being replaced and how it should be replaced. Need I continue ... ?

Comment: This will raise an error... `re.sub` expects at least 3 arguments (the match pattern, the replacement, and the string to parse)